# How to change phpfox change template?

Tags: phpfox

I have a phpfox project, I want to change the template on the original website, how do I do it? In addition to the need to pay attention to the phpfox version of the problem, what issues should be noted?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using phpFox 4.6.0 or above. You can go to adminCP -> Appearance -> Themes -> Select a theme (click edit) -> There is a small icon (^) on left bottom, click it and select "Set as default theme" -> Wait the page is loaded -> Done.

Regards